# Python - Django - pyexcel-xlsx - Could not able to import the Data from Two different sheets into two Models

Tags: python, django, python-import, pyexcel

Trying to import data from two sheets in a XLSX file to two different models - Not able to lead the Data.
I am using pyexcel package for the importing xlsx data.
I am following http://django.pyexcel.org/en/latest/

Note: I have tried to load the data from single sheet & Single Model. This was successfully loaded with out any issue.

But, I am getting the issue when importing the two sheet data into two different models (With foreign key relation)

Models Used:

```
        class Supplier(models.Model):
            Supplier_Number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
            Supplier_Name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
            Supplier_Contracting_Entity =  models.CharField(max_length=150)
            Applicable_Brands =  models.CharField(max_length=150)
            Currency_To_Be_Paid =  models.CharField(max_length=3)
            Other_Remarks =  models.CharField(max_length=150)
            Term =  models.CharField(max_length=15)
            Notes = models.CharField(max_length=150)
            Fee_Calculation_Basis = models.CharField(max_length=25)

            def __str__(self):
                return self.Supplier_Name

        class Tax_Vat(models.Model):
            Supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            #Supplier_Number = models.IntegerField()
            #-- Above will store the Supplier ID, which is generated automatically
            COUNTRY =models.CharField(max_length=25)
            DEDUCTION_TYPE =models.CharField(max_length=5)
            NGR_FLAG =models.CharField(max_length=5)
            TAX_VAT_RATE = models.FloatField()

            def __str__(self):
                return self.COUNTRY
```

Views.py:

```
            class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
                file = forms.FileField()

            def sup_import(request):
                if request.method == "POST":
                    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

                    def tax_func(row):
                        q = Supplier.objects.filter(Supplier_Number=row[0])[0]
                        row[0] = q
                        return row
                    #if form.is_valid():
                    request.FILES['myfile'].save_book_to_database(
                            models=[Supplier, Tax_Vat],
                            initializers=[None, tax_func],
                            mapdicts=[
                                        {   "Supplier_Number": "Supplier_Number",
                                            "Supplier_Name": "Supplier_Name",
                                            "Supplier_Contracting_Entity":"Supplier_Contracting_Entity",
                                            "Applicable_Brands":"Applicable_Brands",
                                            "Currency_To_Be_Paid":"Currency_To_Be_Paid",
                                            "Other_Remarks":"Other_Remarks",
                                            "Term":"Term",
                                            "Notes":"Notes",
                                            "Fee_Calculation_Basis":"Fee_Calculation_Basis"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "Supplier_Number":"Supplier",
                                            "COUNTRY":"COUNTRY",
                                            "DEDUCTION_TYPE":"DEDUCTION_TYPE",
                                            "NGR_FLAG":"NGR_FLAG",
                                            "TAX_VAT_RATE":"TAX_VAT_RATE"

                                        }
                                    ]
                        )
                    return redirect('Royalty_upload.html')
                   # else:
                        #return HttpResponseBadRequest()
                else:
                    form = UploadFileForm()
                return render(
                    request,
                    'Royalty_upload.html',
                    {
                        'form': form,
                        'title': 'Import excel data into database example',
                        'header': 'Please upload Royalty_Input_Import_Data_All.xlsx:'
                    })
```

Error details:

```
Exception at /royalty_supplier
            Sheet: Supplier does not match any given models.Please be aware of case sensitivity.
            Request Method: | POST
            Request URL: | http://127.0.0.1:8000/royalty_supplier
            Django Version: | 3.0.3
            Exception Type: | Exception
            Exception Value: | Sheet: Supplier does not match any given models.Please be aware of case sensitivity
            Exception Location: | C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\database\importers\django.py in create_sheet, line 85

            Environment:

            Request Method: POST
            Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/royalty_supplier

            Django Version: 3.0.3
            Python Version: 3.7.1
            Installed Applications:
            ['django.contrib.admin',
            'django.contrib.auth',
            'django.contrib.contenttypes',
            'django.contrib.sessions',
            'django.contrib.messages',
            'django.contrib.staticfiles',
            'import_export',
            'RECON.apps.ReconConfig']
            Installed Middleware:
            ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

            Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
            response = get_response(request)
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
            response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in get_response
            response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\PycharmProjects\MANOJ_IVY\IREC_WEB\RECON\views.py", line 121, in sup_import
            "TAX_VAT_RATE":"TAX_VAT_RATE"
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django_excel_init.py", line 63, in save_book_to_database
            pe.save_book_as(**params)
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\core.py", line 112, in save_book_as
            return sources.save_book(book, **dest_keywords)
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\internal\core.py", line 56, in save_book
            return _save_any(a_source, book)
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\internal\core.py", line 60, in _save_any
            a_source.write_data(instance)
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\plugins\sources\db_sources.py", line 111, in write_data
            **self._keywords
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\plugins\renderers\django.py", line 75, in render_book_to_stream
            **keywords
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py", line 131, in save_data
            **keywords
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py", line 148, in store_data
            writer.write(data)
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\book.py", line 218, in write
            sheet_writer = self.create_sheet(sheet_name)
            File "C:\Users\manoj.remala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\database\importers\django.py", line 85, in create_sheet
            + "Please be aware of case sensitivity."

            Exception Type: Exception at /royalty_supplier
            Exception Value: Sheet: Supplier does not match any given models.Please be aware of case sensitivity.
```

Comment: Also, tried another scenario with data models column names in lower case.
But the result is same.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please check the sheet name! it expects your sheet to be: model._meta.model_name, which is most likely to be lower case.